# ArulesVIZ interactive plot - Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, arules

I want to create a shiny web app for association mining. One of the thing I want to do is to implement an interactive plot from the package arulesVIZ.

So I have the following code:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(DT)
    library(data.table)
    library(arules)
    library(arulesViz)

    df_transac <-read.table("C:/Users/pauljacq/Desktop/splits/Association     files/ns_transactions.csv",header=T, sep=",")
    t<-read.transactions("C:/Users/pauljacq/Desktop/splits/Associationfiles/ns_transactions.csv", format='single',cols=c('shipment_archive_id','ASIN'),sep=",")

    rules_t <- apriori(t, 
               parameter = list(support = 0.0001, confidence = 0.0001, minlen=2, maxlen=5, ext=TRUE ), 
               control = list(verbose=TRUE))

    rules_table<-data.table(lhs=labels(lhs(rules_t)), rhs=(labels(rhs(rules_t))), quality(rules_t))

    ui<- basicPage(
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("File", DT::dataTableOutput("df_transac")),
          tabPanel("Rules", DT::dataTableOutput("rules")),
          tabPanel("Graph", plotOutput("graph"))
        )
      )
    )

    server <- function(input, output) {
      output$df_transac = DT::renderDataTable({
        df_transac
      })
      output$rules = DT:: renderDataTable({
        rules_table
      })
      output$graph = renderPlot({
        plot(rules_t,method="scatter",interactive=T)
      })
    }
    shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

The app works great when I have

```
    plot(rules_t,method='scatter",interactive=F)
```

However, when I have

```
    plot(rules_t,method='scatter",interactive=T)
```

I have the following error:

```
    Error in convertUnit: 'x' argument must be a unit object
```

Any solution, idea, or reference to previous work is very welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because it seems that shiny does not pass click locations on to the function `grid.locator` from package `grid`. Install the latest arulesViz version and use

```
plot(rules_t, method = "scatter", engine = "htmlwidget")
```

instead. This will create a htmlwidget and should work fine in shiny.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However the widget is populated in the Viewer section of my RStudio. Not sure how to embed it in the actual app?

Comment: Update: WORKING SOLUTION
So the engine="htmlwidget" trick worked. Though I needed to update from renderPlot / plotOutput to renderPlotly / plotlyOutput. 

Thanks a lot @Michael Hahsler